# Improving non-duplicate badly asked questions instead of closing

Tags: discussion

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39863809/print-smallest-integer-value-java) is the question I have in mind. I do not know if it is a duplicate, but let's assume that it is not.

The question is poorly asked and has a poor title, hence all the downvotes. I wonder: If the title is edited to something like *"Retrieving the smaller of two numbers"*, and the question being along the lines of *"If I have two numbers `num1` and `num2`, how do I get the smallest one the easiest way?"*, it would be a clear, specific question, and worth asking, however trivial it might seem. Perhaps it is not even that trivial, since a lot of people (myself included) would use conditions, instead of the simple [`Math.min()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#min(int,%20int)), simply because we aren't too familiar with the `Math` class. I think a rather good answer could be written for this question that draws attention to the `Math` class, mentioning the different numerical primitives (the question need not be about integers).

A lot of people say *"A quick Google search will get you your answer; this is a completely unnecessary question:"*, but since when does a question become bad because answers to it already exists on the web? Isn't the goal of Stack Overflow to build a knowledge base?

If the question is bad, why are questions like *"What is SQL injection?"* and *"What is the difference between default, public, private, and protected?"* so well recieved? They fall into the same category.

---

**TL;DR:** My suggestion is the following:

```
Question q = printSmallestIntegerValueJava.clone();
if(onTopic(q.improve()))
    printSmallestIntegerValueJava.improve().reOpen();
```

---

On second thought, perhaps it is just better to close it and write the better question and answering it yourself. The reputation will go to the correct person, and nobody else has to "waste" their time answering the question when you can do it yourself.

Comment: @AndrewL. Duplicates should be closed of course. I am talking about non-duplicate questions (*"the first of these kinds of questions"* as you put it).

Comment: For that question, there's also a certain reaction to somebody asking for the solution to a homework problem. (It's also never been closed.)

Answer (score 5):

Unless you are 110% sure the question is useful for future and you know how to edit it to meet SO standards it is better (from site point of view) to spend your effort on other questions.

I would caution against asking similar question yourself - unless you understand and address reasons of the votes on original will receive similar downvotes. Also asking self-answered question is hard - make sure to check existing Meta posts on it.

---

Downvotes on main site mainly reflect amount of research author put into the  question. The on you've linked is *somewhat* lacking to show any research.

Sometimes such downvoted questions may actually be useful for the future and hence can/should be improved and answered. Most of  them so can just be collected by [Roomba](https://stackoverflow.com/help/roomba) later.

Indeed you personally can spend time and improve question to be up to SO quality bar and provide corresponding answer. Note that you will unlikely get much payback for your time as OP for such questions frequently just need code and not an explanation and question itself unlikely to recover from downvotes without significant promotion on your side.

For everyone else it is generally better (from site's point of view) to answer questions where OP put some effort and demonstrated at least basic understanding of the subject.

Back to linked question: it is almost impossible to improve "do my homework" question to meet SO standards. The question "how to compare two numbers" is definitely answered in most basic book/tutorial of any language (and definitely for Java) - adding yet another one to SO would not be useful. My rule of thumb is if answer is on first 20 pages of basic language book it is not worth to be on SO.